# installing requirements with pip inside a python script

Tags: python-3.x

I need to install packages using Python that is supposed to perform the same as the following command line:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

note: I need to run this command on a virtual environment

I didn't succeed to do that with os.system.

Comment: Can you show us your requirements.txt?

Comment: "I didn't success" is totally useless. Post the code you've tried and explain with all details (traceback, error message, whatever) how it "didn't success".

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
import sys

def install(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])

install('xlrd') #example - this will install xlrd package
```

Use `sys.executable` to ensure that you will call the same pip associated with the current runtime.